# Using react-native-bootsplash with RN 71

Tags: react-native

The current implementation of RN-bootsplash works fine with RN 70 but on with RN 71 they changed AppDelegate.mm from this

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: 
(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
  RCTAppSetupPrepareApp(application);

  RCTBridge *bridge = [[RCTBridge alloc] initWithDelegate:self 
launchOptions:launchOptions];

  NSDictionary *initProps = [self prepareInitialProps];
  UIView *rootView = RCTAppSetupDefaultRootView(bridge, @"RNBootSplashExample", initProps);

  self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
  UIViewController *rootViewController = [UIViewController new];
  rootViewController.view = rootView;
  self.window.rootViewController = rootViewController;
  [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

  [RNBootSplash initWithStoryboard:@"BootSplash" rootView:rootView];

  return YES;
}
```

to this

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: 
(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
  self.moduleName = @"RNBootSplashExample";
  return [super application:application 
 didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];
}
```

Now the implementation from the docs no longer work.I get this error `use of undeclared identifier 'rootView'`

`#import >React/RCTRootView.h>` is also removed on RN71

Answer (score 1):

The README for this package will be updated when RN71 is released but this seems to work for now

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application 
didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions 
{
  self.moduleName = @"app";
  [super application:application 
didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];
   [RNBootSplash initWithStoryboard:@"BootSplash" 
rootView:self.window.rootViewController.view];
 return YES;
}
```

[source](https://github.com/zoontek/react-native-bootsplash/issues/421)

Answer (score 0):

This is the new way to do it:

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "RNBootSplash.h" // ⬅️ add the header import

// …

@implementation AppDelegate

// …

// ⬇️ Add this before file @end
- (UIView *)createRootViewWithBridge:(RCTBridge *)bridge
                          moduleName:(NSString *)moduleName
                           initProps:(NSDictionary *)initProps {
  UIView *rootView = [super createRootViewWithBridge:bridge
                                          moduleName:moduleName
                                           initProps:initProps];

  [RNBootSplash initWithStoryboard:@"BootSplash" rootView:rootView]; // ⬅️ initialize the splash screen

  return rootView;
}

@end
```

source: https://github.com/zoontek/react-native-bootsplash/blob/master/README.md